# alineación de divs horizontal y verticalmente flexbox

Tags: html5, bootstrap-4, sass, flexbox, flex

Tengo un componente de Angular el cual me saca varias cajas las cuales cada cual tiene una altura distinta y estoy intentando que cuando hace el salto de línea, las cajas de esa fila se coloquen justo debajo de la inmediatamente superior dejando un pequeño espacio con la de arriba

HTML

```
<div class="container-summary">
  <div [ngClass]="{'container-summary-box-general': page === 'general', 'container-summary-box-clinical':page === 'clinical' }" class="container-summary-box bg-summary py-2 px-2 mx-2 my-2">
    <div class="row">
        <h4 class="title">{{ title }}</h4>
      <div class="pos-data" *ngIf="category?.Examinations!.length == 0">{{ 'sin_datos' | translate | uppercase }}</div>
      <div *ngIf="category?.Examinations!.length > 0" class="contenido-datos-resumen">
        <div *ngFor="let item of category?.Examinations">
          <app-componente1 *ngIf="category?.Enum != EnumExaminationCategory.BEHAVORIAL && (item.Type=='guid' || item.Type=='string' || item.Type=='int')" [item]="item"></app-componente1>
          <app-componente2 *ngIf="category?.Enum == EnumExaminationCategory.BEHAVORIAL" [item]="item"></app-componente2>
          <app-componente3 *ngIf="item.Type == 'boolean'" [item]="item"></app-componente3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SASS

```
.container-summary{
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  align-items:baseline;
}
.pos-contenedor {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(20% - 50px/2);
  top: calc(20% - 50px/2);
  width: 75%;
}
.pos-cont-summary{
  padding: 1.5em 0;
  width: 90%;
}
.contenido-datos-resumen{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
.txt-center{
  text-align: center;
}
.txt-left{
  text-align: left;
}

.bg-summary{
  background-color: $dark-summary;
}
.txt-resumen {
  color: $white;
}
h4.title{
  position: relative;
  left: 1em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
.container-summary-box{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 1em .5em;
  margin: .5em;
}
.container-summary-box-general{
  width: 25em;
}

.container-summary-box-clinical{
  min-width: 10em;
  width: 20em;
}
```

Alguien me podría ayudar por favor.

Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me tendría que ajustar las cajas mas o menos así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que hay alguna forma usando flex, estoy buscando y probando varias formas pero no me funciona esta recolocación

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48471053/5525964

Comment: Esta solución no me sirve, ya que está maquetado como si fueran columnas y lo que yo estoy haciendo es una fila que cuando llega al 3º elemento hace salto de línea

Comment: Cierto, combínalo con esto: https://medium.com/@henrylepa/how-to-create-a-great-bootstrap-masonry-design-with-bootstrap-4-70551e6419d1 ahí se establece el número de columnas por cada breakpoint.

Comment: Usando el masonry, también le puedo poner el `column-count: 3;` pero me desordena los elementos, los más pequeños  los pone en la 1º columna, en la 2º columna los que son un poco más altos y en la ultima los más grandes y lo que estoy intentando es que me queden como en la imagen, sin importar el tamaño del elemento de cada columna que se vaya ajustando y colocando en su sitio

Comment: @Lobos sabes de algún ejemplo que haga esto pero en vez de que el flujo sea vertical, es decir, en columnas, sea horizontal?